# Bug Finding, HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm having a really difficult time finding the bugs in seemingly simple HTML/Javascript pages I am designing for a class. I have spent hours looking over code for this pages (and 3 others that are driving me crazy). I wonder if there is some syntax that slipped by me? In this page, we are to write a script that will decipher if a customer has gone over their credit limit. In this page and the other 3, the onclick event does not seem to be working. Here is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Homework 3 Part 3</title>
<style type="text/css">
tr.visiting {background-color: #000000; }


h1.header {color: #333333;} 
.creditbox { 

    background-color: #ffcc66;
    width: 60%;
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}

table {
    text-align: right;
}
td.visiting {background-color: #000000; }
input {text-align: right;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

function creditCalc() 
{
    var account, credLim, begBalance, totalCharged, credit, balance, endBalance;

    account = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.accountNum.value);
    credLim = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.creditLimit.value);
    begBalance = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.beginningBalance.value);
    totalCharged = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.amtCharged.value);
    credit = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.creditsApplied.value);   

    balance = begBalance + totalCharged;
    endBalance = balance - credit;

    documemt.creditLimitForm.creditDisplay.value("Account Number:  " + account + "\nCredit Limit:  " + credLim + "\nBeginning Balance: " + begBalance + "\nTotal Charged this month:  " + totalCharged + "\nTotal credits this month:  " + credit + "\nCredit Available:  " + endBalance);

document.getElementById("creditAvailable").innerHTML = endBalance;

}

/*]]>*/
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor = "#ffffff" alink = "#FFFFCC" link = "#FFFFCC" vlink = "#FFFFCC">
<table id="border" width="70%" align ="center" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="hw3Banner.jpg" alt="Homework Banner" align="middle" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table border="1" width="500" align ="center" bgcolor="#666666" cellpadding="2.5">
     <tr><td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3.html">HW 3 Main</a></td>
     <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt1.html">Part 1</a></td>
     <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt2.html">Part 2</td>
     <td class="visiting" align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt3.html">Part 3</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt4.html">Part 4</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt5.html">Part 5</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt6.html">Part 6</a></td></tr></table>

<br />
<div class="creditbox" align="center" >
<form name="creditLimitForm" action="">
<br />
<h1 class="header">Customer Credit Limit Check</h1>
<br />


<table class="creditLimitForm">
<tr>
<td>Customer Account Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="accountNum" name="accountNum" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1st of Month Balance: </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="beginningBalance" name="beginningBalance" size="15" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Total charged by customer this month: </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="amtCharged" name="amtCharged" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total credits applied to account </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="creditsApplied" name="creditsApplied" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Allowed Credit Limit</td>
<td>$<input type="text" id= "creditLimit" name="creditLimit" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="creditDisplay"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="creditCalc();" value="Check Credit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />

<p>Credit Available: </p>
<p id="creditAvailable"></p>

</form>
<br />
<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any good de-buggers who can come to the rescue?

Comment: How about your browser's debugger?

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but you should ditch the XML prolog, doctype and syntax. Use plain `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The XHTML transitional DOCTYPE (which dates back to 2000) was only intended for browsers that don't understand XML and aid the transition from HTML to XML that never happened, so just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug for Firefox or Chrome's built-in debugging tools (or similar tools for other browsers), it will make your life easier...

As to your specific problem, `onclick` should indeed be calling the function, so the error must be somewhere in the `creditCalc` function. At the very least go to the error console in your browser and post the output here if you're still having trouble; without any error message it makes it much harder to guess what the problem might be.

Edit: It's also possible that there might not be any errors in the error console, which believe it or not is also useful information to those answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

On chrome it is very easy to find bugs in javascript .
You have to just do a right click before load or reloading the page in chrome . and select

```
inspect element
```

than on the bottom tool bar .look for `Console` click on it and you will be able to see any javascript error in your file .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Homework 3 Part 3</title>
<style type="text/css">
tr.visiting {background-color: #000000; }


h1.header {color: #333333;} 
.creditbox { 

    background-color: #ffcc66;
    width: 60%;
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}

table {
    text-align: right;
}
td.visiting {background-color: #000000; }
input {text-align: right;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

function creditCalc() 
{
var account, credLim, begBalance, totalCharged, credit, balance, endBalance;

    account = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.accountNum.value);
    credLim = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.creditLimit.value);
    begBalance = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.beginningBalance.value);
    totalCharged = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.amtCharged.value);
    credit = parseInt(document.creditLimitForm.creditsApplied.value);   

    balance = begBalance + totalCharged;
    endBalance = balance - credit;
/*
    documemt.creditLimitForm.creditDisplay.value("Account Number:  " + account + "\nCredit Limit:  " + credLim + "\nBeginning Balance: " + begBalance + "\nTotal Charged this month:  " + totalCharged + "\nTotal credits this month:  " + credit + "\nCredit Available:  " + endBalance);*/

document.getElementById("creditAvailable").innerHTML = "Account Number:  " + account + "\nCredit Limit:  " + credLim + "\nBeginning Balance: " + begBalance + "\nTotal Charged this month:  " + totalCharged + "\nTotal credits this month:  " + credit + "\nCredit Available:  " + endBalance;

}

/*]]>*/
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor = "#ffffff" alink = "#FFFFCC" link = "#FFFFCC" vlink = "#FFFFCC">
<table id="border" width="70%" align ="center" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="hw3Banner.jpg" alt="Homework Banner" align="middle" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table border="1" width="500" align ="center" bgcolor="#666666" cellpadding="2.5">
     <tr><td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3.html">HW 3 Main</a></td>
     <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt1.html">Part 1</a></td>
     <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt2.html">Part 2</td>
     <td class="visiting" align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt3.html">Part 3</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt4.html">Part 4</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt5.html">Part 5</a></td>
    <td align = "center"><font face ="baskerville" color="#FFFFCC" /><a href="homework3pt6.html">Part 6</a></td></tr></table>

<br />
<div class="creditbox" align="center" >
<form name="creditLimitForm" action="">
<br />
<h1 class="header">Customer Credit Limit Check</h1>
<br />


<table class="creditLimitForm" id="creditLimitForm">
<tr>
<td>Customer Account Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="accountNum" name="accountNum" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1st of Month Balance: </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="beginningBalance" name="beginningBalance" size="15" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Total charged by customer this month: </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="amtCharged" name="amtCharged" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total credits applied to account </td>
<td>$<input type="text" id="creditsApplied" name="creditsApplied" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Allowed Credit Limit</td>
<td>$<input type="text" id= "creditLimit" name="creditLimit" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="creditDisplay"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="creditCalc();" value="Check Credit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />

<p>Credit Available: </p>
<p id="creditAvailable"></p>

</form>
<br />
<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  the problem with your this line otherwise its working fine.just try with alert instead.

     documemt.creditLimitForm.creditDisplay.value("Account Number:  " + account + "\nCredit    Limit:  " + credLim + "\nBeginning Balance: " + begBalance + "\nTotal Charged this month:  " + totalCharged + "\nTotal credits this month:  " + credit + "\nCredit Available:  " + endBalance);
```

this is creating problem.

documemt.creditLimitForm.creditDisplay.value

try alert and check.